# error: Please install the PostgreSQL server development packages and re-run configure

Tags: django, postgresql, ubuntu, postgis, geodjango

I am trying to install the Postgis on my ubuntu system for django framework. But everytime when i run the command ./configure it gives me error

```
 error: the PGXS Makefile /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk cannot be found. Please install the PostgreSQL server development packages and re-run configure.
```

I have already installed postgres on my system and has also created the user. But i am unable to install the Postgis on my system. I have gone through the many instructions i found on Internet but failed to install it.

Please tell me the solution of this error so that i can install Postgis on ubuntu.
help will be highly appreciated

Comment: For future reference this is really more appropriate for superuser.com or serverfault.com not stackoverflow.com; see the tour and FAQ.

Comment: Why are you building postgis from scratch? Try the [apt repository](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt).

Comment: Okay @Craig Ringer, further i will ask sch questions on the sites mentioned you. Thank you

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Agreed, should just `apt-get install postgis2_93`. See http://postgis.net/install/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you're using PostgreSQL from http://apt.postgresql.org/ :

```
apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.3
```

While you're at it, as @BurhanKhalid points out, you should just be installing PostGIS from packages, rather than from source, [as the PostGIS web page explains](http://postgis.net/install/):

```
apt-get install postgis2_93
```

Comment: Yes, it resolved that error but now i am getting another error which is `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot determine PostGIS version for database "mentorhip62". GeoDjango requires at least PostGIS version 1.3. Was the database created from a spatial database template?` . I created the database from spatial template as described in django.

Comment: @SajidAhmad In modern PostGIS versions, you usually `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` instead. But anyway, that's a separate question. If you're still stuck after working on it for a while, post a new question and link back to this one for context.

Comment: @SajidAhmad Also, see the update. You should just install PostGIS from packages like the PostGIS website says.

Answer (score 2):

Install postgreSql

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

Install Postgis.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwibber-daily/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.3
```

create database in Postgresql

```
createuser -U postgres username -S -D -R
psql -U postgres -c "alter role username with password 'passhere';"
createdb -U postgres -T template_postgis -O username dbname
```

if you do not have the template_postgis in the postgresql then
switch to user postgres and run

```
sudo su postgres
createdb template_postgis
createlang plpgsql template_postgis
```

Now for creating the extansions

```
psql -d dbname -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
psql -d dbname -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;"
```

Comment: You don't really need `template_postgis` anymore, it's just a relic from before extensions existed. These days you might as well just `CREATE EXTENSION` in each DB you need PostGIS in.

Answer (score 0):

For PostgreSQL 11, you need to install `postgresql-11-postgis-2.5` and `postgresql-11-postgis-2.5-scripts` as described [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/postgresql-11-postgis-2.5).

```
sudo apt install postgresql-11-postgis-2.5
sudo apt install postgresql-11-postgis-2.5-scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this command :

```
sudo apt install postgis
```